# Sitecore.React null reference error on ReactSettingsProvider

Tags: sitecore-react

I am trying to make React work with a Sitecore 9 instance using https://github.com/GuitarRich/sitecore.react as reference. There were no build errors but upon publishing it, I encountered this error: *"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"*

In addition to the github reference above, I also installed the Sitecore.React and Sitecore.React.Web Nuget packages to the Foundation, Feature and Project projects but I still encounter the problem.

I think that the ReactSettingsProvider.Current is null but I am unable to find where it should be instantiated and/or given a value. Any help is much appreciated!
[image]

Comment: Have you confirmed if the necessary `Sitecore.React.config` is somewhere in your App_Config\Include folder? It should be in a `Sitecore.React` subfolder.

Comment: Just to add, the instantiation of that object occurs in the property accessor for `ReactSettingsProvider.Current` itself. By calling it, it will attempt to create it, using `Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject`

Comment: Yes I have the Sitecore.React.config under App_Config\Include\Sitecore.React, using its default values.
I was also wondering where to place the server.min.js and client.min.js on the site's folder in inetpub.